# Creating a node to which users can add fields in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I would like users to be able to create multiple text fields and select "yes" or "no" on one of 3 options for that field.

For instance:

```
Text field = "24/7 support", option 1=(y/n), option 2=(y/n), option 3= (y/n)
Text field = "bon-bons", option 1=(y/n), option 2=(y/n), option 3= (y/n)
```

... with up to 25 text fields in that content type.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish that?

Basically I need to implement a system, where users can create and edit a "Features list" easily. then assign each one of those features to one of 3 packages.

Comment: I made an edit to make the text in your question a bit less condensed and easier to understand. Please, double check me, and make any needed corrections. Additionally, I assume you want to do this programmatically? A little more context would help.

Comment: What is the "6n" string for the third option?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a grid field. I don't see how a text field would be useable for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

1) First create a content type with 25 fields and the 3 options you mentioned.
* As per your post you mentioned you only want upto 25 posts .

2) Use jquery for displaying only one field and they can always click on a more link for additional fields.

If you don't know jquery and how to implement this then  revert back.

Cheers,
Vishal